# Windows 10 push notifications in Unity

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I have been looking all over and I cannot get notifications in Unity to work without the nasty PowerShell popup needed.

## My investigations

Through my investigations, I've found many ways to achieve my goals but only 1 can unsatisfactorily solve my issues. Hopefully, the community here can provide some assistance.

1. The first option that I found was that you can create notifications with PowerShell commands. Unfortunately, this isn't ideal as when it is ran, the PowerShell will flash on the users screen and that can be very unsettling for users. It is also very hard to customize the code as there is inadequate documentation. **If you know of a way to customize PowerShell notifications and run PowerShell commands in Unity without running PowerShell then that would solve my issue,**
2. The second option that I ran across was the [Microsoft documentation for creating a toast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=uwp) but no matter what I try, I cannot get it to work. The closest I got was by adding a plugin folder to my assets, and adding microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.7.1.2.zip\lib\netstandard1.4\Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.dll to the plugins folder but then I get the error .Show() is not a command. Which meant that I can create the toast object but not display it.
3. Another option is to create a python script but I assume I'd encounter similar issues.
4. The last option that I've seen was using some 3rd party API called burned toast but I can see that I would have the issues from attempts 1 and 2 going that route.
5. The last option that I've seen are $60+ assets on the Unity Asset store but there is no guarantee that those will work at all or on Windows. Not to mention, spending money on what should be free is unheard of.